# Keeping separate animated object attached to character

Tags: animation, parent

I have my little robot guy and he has an electricity animation that plays while the game is active. I have it attached and working correctly alongside the his regular animations in Blender. But in Unity it doesnt play the electrical animation at all and it also has an incorrect location and rotation.
To create the electricity i used the displacement mod and animated the Empty that controlled the electricity. Then i attached the "Power Cell" to the body bone as a relative.

Is this the best way of attaching/setting up dynamic objects that are part of another mesh, or is there a better way?

[image: Character in Blender]

[image: Character in Unity]

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: Thats not gonna change the problem. I didnt have time to post at home, so i took a picture. Can you actually give me helpful information please? This does not help